# Paging in listview control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I have some tutorial/sample code of using datapager in a asp.net listview control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Of course you can**

Rick Strahl's Web Blog of [ListView and DataPager](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/127340.aspx) should help

Answer (score 1):

scott gu's blog is one of my favorite resources for asp.net stuff.

he had done an excellent tutorial on listview and datapager [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx)

Comment: His name is "Scott Guthrie". ;-)