# How to implement paging in listView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Paging in listview control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701616/paging-in-listview-control)

I would like to know how I can implement paging on listview control. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: @psobhan, any reason why you are trying to use a ListView as if it was a Grid? for Grid layout unless really not possible a Grid is more suitable instead of making incredible effort to customize and modify a listview until it behaves like a grid. my opinion of course...

Comment: This article explains how to implement it: http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/100_Paging_in_ListView_in_ASPNet_35.aspx

Comment: @Davide Piras, I wanted to include images and links, hence opted for ListView.

Comment: not really, grids also support links, images and any kind of templated item...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ListViewWithDataPager.aspx) of using `asp:DataPager` to implement paging in listView.